# Modern SSDs need user-defined overprovisioning?

Tags: linux, ssd

I just bough a Kingston 120GB SSD for a Linux desktop. Reading their website, it looks like the drive is actually 128GB in physical size, but it has a factory-determined overprovisioning of 7%, which gets it down to the advertised 120GB.

Do I have to keep another 7% free when partitioning the drive, as oriented in some SSD related answers, or can I use the whole 120GB?

Comment: A 128GB SSD is a 128GB of storage operating systems don't care, they are not made aware, there is extra storage that's left up to the firmware.

Comment: What's your goal, keeping performance high, longevity? What's modern (I'm not sure Kingston has a modern one of these)? Maybe mention the drive or the controller (i.e., SF-2281). About how much data will get written a day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the whole 120GB. You can choose to "over-provision" it more if you want. Most SSDs in most typical use will far outlast their economic usefulness as it is, so I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to give your SSD any special treatment. It’ll probably outlive most of your PCs other components anyway.

Multiple endurance tests have shown that SSDs can take a tremendous amount of writes. So make sure to put your swap partition there, too. Otherwise, you’re wasting a lot of potential.